# Jquery Validation not working corectly after form is loaded with an ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have the following form which is loaded into a lightbox after a previous form is submitted by ajax. On submit of this new form the jquery validation works by defualt so for example it recognizes that the form is not valid in that required field is missiong BUT it does not use my custom validation (valid-password) function for this form ad so does not recognise the password should be 8 characters or more.

Any help would be appreciated.

The jquery

```
$('.validate-password').validate({

   rules: {
        password: { 
            required: true,
            minlength:8
                }
            },
   messages: {
        password: {
            required: 'Create a password please',
            minlength: 'At least 8 characters please'
                }                       
           }
}); 

//submit our optin form when we are using a custom button..
$(".submit-form-with-image-button-when-ajax-created").live('click', function(e) {

    var formID = $(this).attr('href');

    //check we have a valid form..
    $(formID).validate();
    if($(formID).valid() == true){

        //its all good so lets submit the form..
        e.preventDefault();
        $('form'+formID).submit();

    } 

    return false;

});
```

The Form which is returned by an ajax call and displayed inside a lightbox..

```
<form action="/auth/create_user" method="post" class="validate-password form top-space20" style="padding-left:25px;" id="create-account-to-activate-voucher-form">

<?php //echo validation_errors(); ?>

    <div class="form-field clear">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?=$client->email;?>" name="email" class="promo-optin fl-space2 size-250" id="email">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?=(isset($client->community_member->first_name)) ? $client->community_member->first_name : '' ;?>" name="first_name" class="promo-optin fl-space2 size-250" id="optin_first_name">
        <input type="hidden" id="signup_redirect" class="" name="signup_redirect" value="<?=(isset($competition->signup_redirect_url) && $competition->signup_redirect_url != '') ? $competition->signup_redirect_url : '/';?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="user_dc" class="" name="user_dc" value="<?=$competition->user_dc;?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="user_dc_reason" class="" name="user_dc_reason" value="<?=$competition->user_dc_reason;?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="single_use_promotion_code" class="" name="single_use_promotion_code" value="<?=$competition_entry[0]->promotion_code;?>"/>
    </div><!-- /.form-field -->                                 

    <div class="form-field clear bt-space10 left">
        <label for="textfield" class="" style="">Create Password (8-16 characters please) <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="password" id="optin_password" class="required promo-optin fl-space2 size-250 active-input "  name="password" value="<?php //echo set_value('display_position', $landing_page_description->display_position);?>"/>
    </div><!-- /.form-field -->                             

    <div class="form-field" style="position:relative; top:30px; left:-22px;">
        <a class="btn btn-large btn-green center submit-form-with-image-button-when-ajax-created" style="" alt="Claim my voucher" href="#create-account-to-activate-voucher-form">
        <span>Start Shopping</span>
        </a>
    </div><!-- /.form-field -->                                                                                             

</form>
```

SOLUTION USED:

immedietly after the original ajax request run validation on the new form id..

I left with "live" but altered the following

$('#create-account-to-activate-voucher-form').validate({

```
rules: {
    password: { 
        required: true,
        minlength:8
                }
           },
  messages: {
    password: {
        required: 'Create a password please',
        minlength: 'At least 8 characters please'
            }                       
           }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try bind instead of live, because live has been deprecated in latest jquery files.

**Like this:**

```
$(".submit-form-with-image-button-when-ajax-created").bind('click', function(e) {
   // do your stuff
});
```

And you need to bind the method again when form is loaded using ajax, because document.ready only binds the events when page loads first time.

Try to bind that again when form is loaded on the DOM.

Comment: Can you expand on how i would do...."bind the method again when form is loaded using ajax" please..

Comment: In your case, ajax is loading component without triggering the page events, so document.ready event will not be triggered. You need to bind the validate() method after the loading call finishes

Comment: thanks. that worked a treat. i had tried something similar earlier but ddidnt realise I needed to put the validation rules as well rather than just calling validate() immedietly after the ajax call